# Buffer reading from sensor

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, buffer

I have a device with accelerometer that connects through Bluetooth to my android tablet. For the tablet I wrote a simple application that draws the graph of the 100 last readngs with the help of achartengine. For this purpose I created a simple buffer that adds new entry and removes the first one:

```
accxSeries.add(time, accX);
if(accxSeries.getItemCount() >= SensorData.MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
    Log.d("XX", ""+accxSeries.getItemCount());
    accxSeries.remove(0);
}
```

Now the `remove(0)` causes

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.getY(XYSeries.java:169)
        at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.initRange(XYSeries.java:83)
        at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.remove(XYSeries.java:140)
        at com.example.workoutgame.BluetoothLogger.onReadData(BluetoothLogger.java:206)
```

**But only sometimes.** Most of the time the code works just fine. I can't trace the origin of this error. The `onReadData` is called when there is incoming bluetooth reading of data.

I even added the logging so I could see some value in the case that this error happens. But for some reason, the adb logcat doesn't show me all the calls of the log function.

I have no idea what to do, do you have some suggestions of how to debug this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at XYSeries.java, line 169. Something referenced there is null.

Comment: Another thing you can try is passing in dummy data instead of real data from the sensor. If it fails with certain values or ranges, that can help you track down the problem.

Comment: I looked at XYSeries.java, and it looks fine. Maybe I'll download the raw achartengine code and debug it from there. I also like Martin's suggestion.